# pmml (randomForestModel) throws errors on different runs ..Error in tree[, 2] : incorrect number of dimension

Tags: r, pmml

While trying to build a simple RF Regression model and exporting as PMML. I find for the data, though model is always built, exporting as PMML is not always successful. For many runs, it throws error. Details below.

Dataset: Sample
[image]

R Code

```
> (model.rf <- randomForest(y~ ., data=updatedDataset,ntree=6)) 

Call:
 randomForest(formula = y~ ., data = updatedDataset,      ntree = 6) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 6
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

          Mean of squared residuals: 166.4923
                    % Var explained: 46.47

> pmml(model.rf)
Now converting tree  1  to PMML
Now converting tree  2  to PMML
Now converting tree  3  to PMML
Now converting tree  4  to PMML
Now converting tree  5  to PMML
Now converting tree  6  to PMML
**Error in tree[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions**
> (model.rf <- randomForest(y~ ., data=updatedDataset,ntree=5))

Call:
 randomForest(formula = y~ ., data = updatedDataset,      ntree = 5) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 5
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

          Mean of squared residuals: 132.1672
                    % Var explained: 57.51
>pmml(model.rf) worked fine.............................................
```

It failed for few others..nothing in particular..

```
> (model.rf <- randomForest(y~ ., data=updatedDataset,ntree=8)) 

Call:
 randomForest(formula = y~ ., data = updatedDataset,      ntree = 8) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 8
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

          Mean of squared residuals: 191.4946
                    % Var explained: 38.43
> #model.rf
> pmml(model.rf)
Now converting tree  1  to PMML
Now converting tree  2  to PMML
Now converting tree  3  to PMML
Now converting tree  4  to PMML
Error in tree[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
> (model.rf <- randomForest(y~ ., data=updatedDataset,ntree=9))

Call:
 randomForest(formula = y~ ., data = updatedDataset,      ntree = 9) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 9
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

          Mean of squared residuals: 155.9007
                    % Var explained: 49.88
> #model.rf
> pmml(model.rf)
Now converting tree  1  to PMML
Now converting tree  2  to PMML
Now converting tree  3  to PMML
Error in tree[, 2] : incorrect number of dimension
```

Reasons for this behavior and how to ensure it works always is the query.

Thanks !

Comment: x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 y
0 0 1 1 0 23.077 31.25
3 3 5 1 0 25 41.212
1 3 1 1 0 24.545 30.278
3 3 9 1 0 22.764 51.472
0 0 1 1 0 23.077 31.25
0 1 0 1 0 25.922 50
9 17 19 1 0 23.023 60.758
1 2 3 1 0 25.564 69.045
8 16 16 1 0 26.545 59.811
0 1 0 1 0 29.793 63.5

Comment: Your x4 column could be a constant, and when rf tries to split it it thews an error. Columns with zero variance should not be included in training sets.

Comment: Thanks for the observation and answer. pmml call was failing hence.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting your random forest model using the [`r2pmml` package](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) instead?

```
r2pmml(model.rf, "MyRandomForest.pmml")
```

Does `r2pmml` succeed, or fail also? The `r2pmml` package is a little bit smarter and faster than the legacy `pmml` package, so perhaps it knows how to handle your model object correctly.